# Parse push notification results 0 sent

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, push-notification

got an issue with push notifications wondering if anyone can help, i am trying to send a push notification to specific users using this query..... which is in a for loop containing PFObjects with the users details. Nothing is wrong with my set up as i have similar code on my messages page(chat) that sends a push for each member. I am retrieving the pushes on the parse database with the correct usernames, but nothing is being sent :/ Don't know what the issue is ? maybe it is worth mentioning that some of the users do not have the installation set up? but i am using a user that does have this set. Any help would be really appreciated my code is below.

```
  var pushQuery:PFQuery = PFInstallation.query()
  pushQuery.whereKey("user", equalTo: pushObject["username"])
  var push:PFPush = PFPush()
  push.setQuery(pushQuery)
  push.setMessage("New Task")
  push.sendPushInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success: Bool, error: NSError!) -> Void in
          if (success){
             println("worked?")
          } else {
             println( "this is an error \(error.localizedDescription)")
          }
  })
```

Comment: do you actually get "worked?" or do you get an "error" back?

Comment: Yeah, sorry i should of said this...because i thought the error was due to the fact it's trying to send to many pushes at once because initially i was using sendPush(nil). But yes dependant on the amount of users returned from query is the amount of time i get back "worked?" and this does work

Comment: so it works in some cases and doesn't work in other cases?

Comment: No in the case of this function i've provided here it doesn't work, but for a separate class where i am sending a new notification when a single user sends a message to another it works fine. Hence why i thought it may be a one-to-one situation, i think whats confusing me is that is be shown on the parse push...but there it says no pushes sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the targeting of the push is the issue here.

```
  pushQuery.whereKey("user", equalTo: pushObject["username"])
```

This line seems like the issue, because the Installation class usually stores the `"user"` key as either just the `objectID` of the `PFUser` or directly as a pointer. Either way, matching on the `username` probably isn't the right way to go about it. What you need is an additional query, that matches on the `username`, and have that return a user, which will match the installation query:

```
var innerQuery : PFQuery = PFUser.query()
innerQuery.whereKey("username", equalTo: pushObject["username"])
var pushQuery = PFInstallation.query()
pushQuery.whereKey("user", matchesQuery: innerQuery)
```

I just translated this from functioning Obj-C code, so I hope it works in Swift, but this is the general idea you need to send a push to an installation based on a user's username.

Comment: Thank you your helpful comment, this was the solution in the end.